# How to not hardcode passwords?

Tags: security, password-protection, password-storage

In my last question "Portable database for storing secrets" [the best answer until now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555076/portable-database-for-storing-secrets/555090#555090) tell to use sqlite-crypt.

Reading sqlite-crypt docs, the new param for open the database is the pass-phrase. Of course, I don't want hardcode the password, so I was thinking what the best, simple and fast method to store that password?

Answer (score 11):

Some options.

1. Ask the user for a passkey (aka they memorize one password to get to all their password) (good idea)
2. Create a key on the first startup of the app, which is then hashed in your own unique way (bad idea)
3. Use a mixture of the above, aka give users the options of one, or two (remember my password checkbox)

Comment: +1 for #3. Some users may have alternative security schemes in place (e.g. full-disk encryption) that make storing the password in a configuration file an acceptably low risk for them.

Answer (score 3):

You pretty well *have* to store it in a user.

Otherwise you're just substituting some other security mechanism for the one you're asking about...

---

[David's point in the comment on Infamy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555222/how-to-not-hardcode-passwords/555238#555238) is well taken. One should allow some flexibility, in case the user is handling protection at a lower layer... So, go vote for Infamy.

Answer (score 2):

Hardcoding is inevitable at some point, unless the password is only ever used interactively.

The best thing you can do in a password-in-file situation is make it damn hard to access it in the first place, and then limit what can be done with it if someone does find it. A rule of thumb is that you shouldn't give more privileges to a password stored in a string than one that you have to type at a prompt.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows you could/should use the [DPAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx), the [Data Protection API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_protection_API) that provides storage encryption.
It's there just for this type of problem.

Encryption of the storage is based on either:

- the user account, so only the logged-in user can access the data. This makes the data transferable to another PC with the exact same user credentials.
- the machine, making the data only accessible on that particular machine setup and not transferable to another PC.

There is a [dnrTV show with Karl Franklin](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=79) showing exactly what's needed to implement this, and other encryption functions.
The source code from the show is also available on the page.

There are, of course, lots of [other articles](http://www.codeproject.com/info/search.aspx?artkw=DPAPI&sbo=kw) on that subject.