# Windows Impersonation from C#

Tags: c#, windows, impersonation

How can a C# program running as LocalSystem impersonate the login identity of another user temporarily? Roughly speaking I have a Windows Service that I'd like to run as LocalSystem but at times impersonate user XYZ (when connecting to a db using windows integrated security).

Most important of all: Is there a way to do this without knowing the other user's password?

Note: if a password is mandatory is there a recommended strategy for storing a password securely (c# and/or vbscript).

Comment: For the Impersonation code see the following two Code Project articles: [http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cpimpersonation1.aspx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cpimpersonation1.aspx) [http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/zetaimpersonator.aspx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/zetaimpersonator.aspx) and the Microsoft KB article they are based upon: [http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q306158](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q306158)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's possible, although it requires you to do a lot of code. See [NtCreateToken](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/Token/NtCreateToken.html) and [CreateToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374780(v=vs.85).aspx). You need SeCreateTokenPrivilege, although that won't be a problem since you're running under NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. You can then use the created token to impersonate inside a thread.

Comment: Thanks. Not much in the way of code samples out there for it though :)

Comment: Note that it's not recommended to run services under LocalSystem, and sysadmins rightly frown on this practice.

Comment: On stackoverflow, I prefer to do/answer what is asked.

Answer (score 13):

Short answer: you can't without the user password or the user calling your service through COM.

To impersonate another user in your process, you have to call [`ImpersonateLoggedOnUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378612.aspx). `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` requires a token handle. There are several ways you can obtain token handle:

- by logging on as the user with [`LogonUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184(VS.85).aspx). This however requires you to know the user password.
- by duplicating an existing token with [`CreateRestrictedToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446583(VS.85).aspx), [`DuplicateToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446616(VS.85).aspx), or [`DuplicateTokenEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446617(VS.85).aspx).
- by opening the token from another process or thread, that already is loggen on as the user, with [`OpenProcessToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379295(VS.85).aspx) or [`OpenThreadToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379296(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 5):

For the password storing part, you may want to have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555222/how-to-not-hardcode-passwords) asked recently.

This was my answer:

You could/should use the [DPAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx), the [Data Protection API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_protection_API) that provides storage encryption.
It's there just for this type of problem.

Encryption of the storage is based on either:

- the user account, so only the logged-in user can access the data. This makes the data transferable to another PC with the exact same user credentials.
- the machine, making the data only accessible on that particular machine setup and not transferable to another PC.

There is a [dnrTV show with Karl Franklin](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=79) showing exactly what's needed to implement this, and other encryption functions.
The source code from the show is also available on the page.

There are, of course, lots of [other articles](http://www.codeproject.com/info/search.aspx?artkw=DPAPI&sbo=kw) on that subject.