# Receiving NTSTATUS: NT code 0x80131904 - NT code 0x80131904 errorr on WMI queries

Tags: bash, wmi, biztalk, nagios

I am writing a nagios bash script in order to receive BizTalk SendPorts status from application server. There is no any network or permission issue. But I'm receiving NT code 0x80131904 error.

```
QUERY="Select * from MSBTS_SendPort where Status='2'"

WMIRESULT=`/usr/local/nagios/bin/wmic --namespace="root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer" --option="client ntlmv2 auth"=Yes -U $CRED //$IPADDRESS "$QUERY"`


[nagios@nagiosmon sy_check_win]$ sh sy_check_bt_sendports MYSERVER MYDOMAIN

**NTSTATUS: NT code 0x80131904 - NT code 0x80131904**

**[wmi/wmic.c:212:main()] ERROR: Retrieve result data.**
```

OK

Comment: Have you seen this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683170/remote-wmi-call-to-biztalk-object-throws-comexception-0x80131904?rq=1

Comment: Thank you @Dijkgraaf . I've made a local script on the target server. It's working properly.