# How can we set/get other users Environment variable in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, environment-variables

User Environment variables are separate for each user account on machine.

Consider the following, I'm logged in with `userA` which is non admin user account, now I want to get/set other user's (say `userB`) environment variable by using C# application running in `userA`'s context.

Is this possible to do? And if so, how could I do this?

Comment: why you want to do that ? it seems a bad application design.

Comment: @pylover:i m executing different scripts frm my c# application. script will be executed in different different users context. i want to share environment variable between c# appln and script. script will modify env var value and i will get changed value in c# appln.also script type is not fixed (can be anything .cmd,.vbs,.ps1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment variables are stored in the registry, so to change them for another user you would have to import their registry hive.

The key for user vars is

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment`

and the key for system vars is

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`

So if you import the current user hive you can change it for other users, or for machine vars change the `HKLM` key from any admin account.

This is messy though and I wouldn't advise you do it.

Or you can use some P/Invoke to use [Impersonation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564153/edit-registry-key-of-other-user)

Comment: every user has an isolated HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry tree.any users may not have to change the other user's entries

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you talking about the `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5...` keys?

Comment: @Bail C:HKEY_CURRENT_USER  have only current users evn var values. i want to modify env var value of other user

Comment: @sailer Yes, but if you import the other users NTUSER.dat file you can edit theirs. See here for a detailed explanation. http://www.ghacks.net/2008/03/12/windows-tip-edit-user-registry-of-other-users/