# VB.Net edit current users registry with elevated rights on Windows 7

Tags: vb.net, windows-7, impersonation

So in IT environments we commonly lock down users profiles to prevent access to the registry, command, prompt, control panel,etc. This can easily be done via GPO.  However, there are times when you need to make a quick change to the users profile when everything is locked down.  Maybe it is to changes the video resolution or the wallpaper, or edit something under the restricted users HKEY_CURRENT_USER.  So it is easy to reboot and login as an admin. Open their registry hive. and rename "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies" to Policies.disabled log them in and make the changes and refresh via gpupdate /force.  But there should be a better way with impersonate user or Run As.  But when you run RunAs as another user it runs it as the admin and you get the Admins HKCU.

How would you make it so you can run an app made in VB.NET that simply deletes "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies" so you can make those changes?

Comment: Perhaps this question could be a starting point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564153/edit-registry-key-of-other-user