# Registry value not getting set

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I am trying to set some Registry values with a small application I done, but after running my program values are not edited...

This is my code:

```
enum KeyLocation
{
    LocalMachine,
    CurrentUser,
}

private static void ChangeRegistry(KeyLocation location, string key, string keyName, RegistryValueKind type, object value)
{
    RegistryKey registryKey = null;

    try
    {
        if (location == KeyLocation.LocalMachine)
            registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(key, true);

        else if (location == KeyLocation.CurrentUser)
            registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(key, true);

        registryKey.SetValue(keyName, value, type);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (registryKey != null)
            registryKey.Close();
    }
}
```

Currently I am trying to block the Sticky keys, so I am calling the above method with the following call:

```
string subkey1 = @"Control Panel\Accessibility\Keyboard Response";
string keyName1 = "Flags";
string newValue1 = "122";
ChangeRegistry(KeyLocation.CurrentUser, subkey1, keyName1, RegistryValueKind.String, newValue1);
```

I also change other values, indicated on this link: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-desktop/i-cant-turn-off-sticky-keys/a7c9fc02-2d0f-4db6-89fb-e36eca3e2ac7

I execute my application, no exception are thrown, so I restart my computer, but the values did not change... I am executing the application with admin rights, providing the correct credentials.

In other part of my program I create and delete other keys, and that works fine... What I am doing wrong? Or at least, how can I debug this?

**EDIT:**

I think I know whats the problem... But I don't know how to solve it.

I am running this application in a regular account, but when I run it I need to give it administrator rights, so when the application runs the keys edited (from `Registry.CurrentUser`, are edited in the admin profile, and not the current logged user). Can this be the problem?

Comment: This code is working fine for me. I don't have to reboot, just have refresh the Registry Editor (View -> Refresh) and it shows the new value fine. How are you checking the value?

Comment: @Quantic After checking your comment, I changed my code to before and after the edit print the value of the key, and I found out that the keys where already updated, could you check my edit and confirm if that can be the problem?

Comment: Your edit makes sense, in which case the answer is probably [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564153/edit-registry-key-of-other-user).

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I solved my problem, it was related with the user, when I runned the app as admin the user account would change to the admin account, so the changes done to the Key Current User would happen in the admin, thats why I didn't saw the changes on my current user. I tried to use the link you gave to solve this, but the impersonation didn't solve my problem, so I followed a simplier approach, I detected the SID of the current user (by detecting the owner of explorer.exe), and then I changed the Keys in the User with that SID in the Key USERS. Thank you for the input @Quantic.