# Connecting To A Database Using Windows Authentication With Different Credentials using C#

Tags: c#

Perhaps someone can help me out here. I'm writing a program in C# to connect to a database on a remote server. The server in question uses Windows Authentication. I'm also not the admin of the server.

In any event to connect to server using SQL Server Management Studio I have to use a different credentials. So I use the runas.exe to connect.

Basically, Something along the lines of:

runas.exe /netonly /user:DIFFERENT_DOMAIN\SAME_USERNAME "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe"

Using the runas.exe is the only way I can connect to the database, if I try running ssms without the runas, I will not connect at all.

So now my question. In the program I'm making in C#. How can I get my program to connect to the same database using different credentials without having to use runas.exe?

I've tried using:

```
Sqlconnection sc = new Sqlconnection();
sc.ConnectionString = "Data Source= myServer;Initial Catalog= myDB;Integrated Security=true";
sc.Open();
```

But I just get "Login failed for user ''. User not associated with a trusted SQL Server Connection."

If I use the above code and Runas.exe with the correct credentials. It will work fine and connect. However I don't want to have to use it.

Anyone have any idea how to get the connection to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can impersonate a domain user from your c# code. There are some examples linked from this question:

[Windows Impersonation from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559719/windows-impersonation-from-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to who said about Windows Impersonation! After looking at that and googling around about Windows Impersonation, I ran into

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
  public static extern bool CreateProcessWithLogonW(
     String             userName,
     String             domain,
     String             password,
     LogonFlags         logonFlags,
     String             applicationName,
     String             commandLine,
     CreationFlags          creationFlags,
     UInt32             environment,
     String             currentDirectory,
     ref  StartupInfo       startupInfo,
     out ProcessInformation     processInformation);
```

And seeing the logon Flag to LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY. It worked perfectly.