# Application/user privileges issues

Tags: c#, privileges, rights

I have built an application using C# which accesses the registry and installation folder for read/write information. A normal user having limited privileges is getting an error while accessing/writing the information (in registry or installation folder).

Is there a way in which all types of users are able to run that application smoothly?

Comment: It sounds like you might be using the wrong locations for certain types of data. During normal usage, you shouldn't be writing data to your install location. [MS Guidelines](http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/6/a/e6aa654f-cccb-421e-9b50-3392e9886084/VistaFileSysNamespaces.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, although it's not completely straightforward.
You're gonna have to impersonate another user (who, in turn, has to have all the required privileges).

Check this question for details: [Windows Impersonation from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559719/windows-impersonation-from-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, the simple and complex. First - install the program per user rather than per computer. Second - to write a service that will operate under the privileged user and perform the necessary procedures (accessing/writing the information) for your application.