# Is there a way to run a C# program under it's own account?

Tags: c#, active-directory

At work we have a program that is a data entry program.  This program moves files as data is being entered, so read/write permissions has to be available for this to occur.  Is there a way to make a C# program run under an account that has these permissions while keeping the users' account more restrictive?  I'm using VS 2010.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559719/windows-impersonation-from-c-sharp

Comment: You want an application on a client machine in a network/domain to run with elevated network/domain permissions without specific user action (IE: runas)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`runas`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) utility - setup a shortcut using it.

It:

> Allows a user to run specific tools and programs with different permissions than the user's current logon provides.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can add [PrincipalPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.principalpermissionattribute.aspx) attribute to control permissions of a single method.
   `[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role ="Administrators")]

   static void CheckAdministrator()

   {

     Console.WriteLine("User is an administrator");

   }`
2. Or use [Application Manifest to elevate UAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756929.aspx)
   `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`

Answer (score 0):

@Oded,

When using the runas utility, do you need to enter the password for the account you're trying to run the program as?