# Error : Login failed for user 'domain\username' using SqlCredential object

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlconnection

I am using below mentioned code when I tried to connect with SQL server. I am geeting  Login failed for user 'domain\username'. I have checked that the user having sysadmin permission in SQL Server & I am using SQL server Express edition.

connection string I used for this "Initial Catalog=Employee;Server=serverName"

```
 public static bool connectSqlClient(string connecton)
     {
         bool isConnect = false;
         try
         {
             string username = @"domain\username";
             string initString = "abcpassowrd";
             // Instantiate the secure string.
             SecureString testString = new SecureString();

             // Use the AppendChar method to add each char value to the secure string. 
             foreach (char ch in initString)
                 testString.AppendChar(ch);

             testString.MakeReadOnly();
             SqlCredential cred = new SqlCredential(username, testString);
             SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connecton, cred);
             conn.Open();
             isConnect = true;
         }
         catch (Exception)
         {
             throw;
         }

         return isConnect;
     }
```

Let me know if I missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, when you add a Login to Sql Server, there are 2 modes.

Sql Server Authentication (which is the "old school" user-name and pwd scenario)

and

"Windows Authentication".
which is where you find a user (domain\username) on your network and add the login.
THIS SCENARIO DOES NOT REQUIRE A PASSWORD TO BE SET/SENT.

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

That is a typical "Windows Authentication" connection string.  You don't set the username/pwd, because the IIDentity is "picked up" from who/whatever is logged into or whose credentials the application is running.

I ~think you want to use Windows-Authentication (since you mention 'domain/username')....but you're setting the pwd as if you were using Sql-Server-Authentication.  Thus "mixing" the 2 models.

as mkross mentions, just because you add the LOGIN, you still need to "link in" the database itself.  If you go to the Security/Logins/ (properties) and go the "User Mapping" selection, you can "Map" to the database, and select a role_membership like "db_datareader" as a low rights role.

APPEND:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcredential%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
 SqlCredential provides a more secure way to specify the password for a login attempt using SQL Server Authentication.

SqlCredential is comprised of a user id and a password that will be used for SQL Server Authentication.
```

So yeah, that's for Sql-Server-Authentication.  Not Windows-Authentication.

you probably just need

```
string myConnectionString = "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;"
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this information. Is there any way to pass the domain user and password?

Comment: Are you asking, can I "impersonate" another identity?  (other than the identity running the application/process) ?

Comment: Yes, You are right. I am asking about the impersonation without using the web.config like we are doing to put the tag in the web.config. can we using the same using code?

Comment: You need to impersonate the user in the APPLICATION, aka, your C# application.  This isn't trivial.  See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559719/windows-impersonation-from-c-sharp   From that point, the simple "Trusted_Connection" connection string should work.

Comment: Your real question is "how do I impersonate a user in a non asp.net c# application".  As you've seen, its fairly simple in asp.net with a web.config setting, but not so much in a winforms/console/wpf application.

Comment: But "SqlCredential" is for "Sql Authentication", now Windows-Authentication.  SqlCredential  will not work for what you are attempting.  Not rubbing it in, "just sayin'", so you don't spend any more time on it.

Comment: Thanks Yes, You are right I checked the same at my end the SqlCredential is used for SQL Authentication.

Answer (score 1):

While you may have created the user did you add that particular user to your actual database?

This tripped me up for a while after I inherited a demo that already had the user created.  When I backed it up and restored it the user was not included and needed to be added back in.

Here you can see the folder **Security** with **Logins** as a sub folder:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiHrb.png

Add the user here first.

Once the login is created you then need to expand your actual database itself and add the login there as well.

Answer (score 0):

After creating the account MAKE SURE TO RESTART THE SERVER INSTANCE!!

I have come across this problem so many times.  You can do this either in the management studio by right clicking the server instance and choosing restart.

[image]

or you can do it through the SQL Server Configuration Manager. Other than that you code looks fine.

[image]