# Impersonation in Windows Service

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a windows service that grabs a data set via SQL connection string from a different server. I need to impersonate a specific user account that has access to this SQL Server database. The code works find if I build it as a console application, but a windows service messes things up.

When building as a windows service, no matter the impersonation, the service tries to connect and authenticate using the machine account (which is wrong) as designated by the error:

> Cannot open database \"DATABASE\" requested by the login. The login
>   failed. Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\MACHINENAME'.

With this snippet of code I use the impersonator class:

```
[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]
    public DataSet GetDataSetSQL(string pSQL)
    {
        DataSet ds = null;
        DbDataAdapter adapter = null;
        try
        {
            using (impers = new Impersonator(impers_uname, impers_domain, impers_password))
            {
                /// Create connection
                using (DbConnection conn = this.factory.CreateConnection())
                {
                    conn.ConnectionString = this.connectionString;

                    /// Create Command
                    using (DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.CommandText = pSQL;

                        adapter = this.factory.CreateDataAdapter();
                        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

                        ds = new DataSet();
                        adapter.Fill(ds);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (adapter != null) adapter = null;
        }
        return ds;
    }
```

Here is where I get the token:

```
if (LogonUser(
                    userName,
                    domain,
                    password,
                    LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                    LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                    ref token) != 0)
                {
                    if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
                    {
                        tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
                        impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                    }
```

I could just run the windows service under the user account, but I want to have that extra level of granularity and also portability.

Anyone have any ideas how impersonation is different between applications and windows services?

**Edit**:

New enums and logonuser function call

```
public enum LogonType
    {
        LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2,
        LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK = 3,
        LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH = 4,
        LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE = 5,
        LOGON32_LOGON_UNLOCK = 7,
        LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT = 8, // Win2K or higher
        LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9 // Win2K or higher
    };

    public enum LogonProvider
    {
        LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0,
        LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT35 = 1,
        LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT40 = 2,
        LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50 = 3
    };

if (LogonUser(
                    userName,
                    domain,
                    password,
                    (int)LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS,
                    (int)LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50,
                    ref token) != 0)
```

Comment: See this [other SO q&a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559719/windows-impersonation-from-c-sharp).

Comment: What specifically from this link? This was the first link I ran across when searching, but it didn't seem helpful.

Comment: The CodeProject links in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/559740/1119545) (maybe the MSDN link as well). The first comment to that is that it works.

Comment: Why not give the service account a login to the server, this is typical setup.

Comment: Like I mentioned in my original post, this works when it is a console application, but not when its compiled into a windows service. My service followed that link to the dot. The person who said that it works was not the OP so who knows what scenario he/she used it for.

Comment: oh... you have to run the service as a specific user https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sys_srv_logon_user.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Hogan, I know about that feature. Using impersonation allows more granularity for me in my code and also allows the service to be installed on servers without giving out the password.

Answer (score 1):

Regards to the 4th parameter the function [LogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx),  you're using LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE.

This logon type is intended for users who will be interactively using the computer, such as a user being logged on by a terminal server, remote shell, or similar process. but Windows service is not in this category, so I thing you should use LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE instead.

Comment: I've tried using that logon type and got "Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer."

Comment: try change it to LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, while you also need to change the 5th parameter to LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50

Comment: Set to 
`private const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 9; 
private const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 3;`

Same error.

Comment: I did. LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS translates to 9, and LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50 translates to 3. Am I missing something? Doesn't matter what I call the variables.

Comment: LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE and LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT are defined by Windows header file, you should not use these as variable names.